# Duplicate key value generating uuidv4 in sequelize model

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, sequelize.js, uuid

Hi i'm noob with ts and express.

I have defined an uuid type code attribute but always return the same value.

```
'use strict';

const { v4: uuidv4 } = require('uuid');
const { Model, Sequelize } = require('sequelize');

module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {

 class Hotel extends Model {
   static associate(models) {
   }
 }

 Hotel = sequelize.define('Hotel', {
   code: {
     type: DataTypes.UUID,
     defaultValue: DataTypes.UUIDV4,
     primaryKey: true,
     allowNull: false,
   },
   name: {
     type: DataTypes.STRING(256),
     allowNull: false,
   }
 },
 {
   sequelize,
   tableName: 'hotel_hotel',
   schema: 'public',
   timestamps: false,
 });

 return Hotel;
```

};

The Postgres sql create:

```
BEGIN;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS public.hotel_hotel (
  code uuid NOT NULL,
  "name" character varying(256) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY(code)
);
COMMIT;
```

The first time works well:

> Executing (default): INSERT INTO "public"."hotel_hotel" ("code","name") VALUES ($1,$2) RETURNING "code","name";

But second insert object fails:

> Executing (default): INSERT INTO "public"."hotel_hotel" ("code","name") VALUES ($1,$2) RETURNING "code","name";

> 2022-12-21 07:58:04.561 UTC [65] ERROR:  duplicate key value violates unique constraint "hotel_hotel_pkey"

> 2022-12-21 07:58:04.561 UTC [65] DETAIL:  Key (code)=(a66eef94-d28e-4dc7-81f7-6346d2c255f3) already exists.

Comment: can you share the part where you create using `sequelize`

Answer (score 1):

You can let `sequelize` auto generate the ids

```
{
  type: DataTypes.UUID,
  defaultValue: DataTypes.UUIDV4 // Or DataTypes.UUIDV1
}
```

As mentioned in the [docs](https://sequelize.org/docs/v6/core-concepts/model-basics/#uuids)

> For UUIDs, use DataTypes.UUID. It becomes the UUID data type for PostgreSQL and SQLite, and CHAR(36) for MySQL. Sequelize can generate UUIDs automatically for these fields, simply use DataTypes.UUIDV1 or DataTypes.UUIDV4 as the default value:

Comment: This does not work, always generate the same uuid value.

Comment: That is not possible, if you have defined the column as `PRIMARY KEY`, the insert query itself will fail if it gives same `UUID`. Also, if you generate the `uuid` there is almost no probability for repeating, you should check any other place where you might be setting the value explicitly.

Comment: What @Kaneki21 wrote is absolutely correct. If you get this error, most likely you are querying your db on Hotels and using somewhere the id which already is in the Database. Generating same uiids again and again, is i would dare to say, impossible.